# Arithmetic Progression

Tags: nt.number-theory

Show that for all $a,d,n\in\mathbb{N}$  :
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{1}{a+id}\notin\mathbb{N}$$

It means that a finite sum of reciprocal of arithmetic progression of natural numbers with at lest two elements cannot be a natural number again.

Comment: A bit more background? This is worded as homework...

Comment: I saw this problem in a book of number theory which is written for mathematics olympiad

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/39326/reference-request-unit-fraction-equally-spaced-denominators-not-integer

Comment: I think you should read this first before firing off questions at MO: http://mathoverflow.net/help (specifically the part about Asking). We tend not to want to be a clearinghouse for contest or olympiad problems -- sorry.